# Incremental if loop function in the incremental loop of the main

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I'm trying to make a Snake Vs block game, but for this part of the code, I only want to put values in my grid, from my 'count' variable. I do not want this variable to set to 0 every time I call it. So I need to find a way so that my counter does not reset every time I call it.

I'm trying to put an incremental loop function in the main, in it's incremental loop too.

Problem is, the value of the function always return to 0, because it reset to zero every time I call the function. ( Because of the loop)

How can I stop it from resetting to 0 every time I call it? Putting it in a global variable works, but I cannot do that for my assignment.

Here are the 2 parts of my code that I'm talking about:

```
public static int choix_case (int nbColonnes) {
    int max = maximum(nbColonnes);
    int random_value = RandomValue();
    int count = 0;

    do {
       if ( random_value == 1) {
          count++;    
       }

       if (random_value == 2) {
          count++; 
       }

       if (random_value == 3) {
          count++;
       }

    } while(count <= max);

    return count;
}
```

And then :

```
public static void obtenirNouvelleGrille(int[][] grille, int nbLignes, int nbColonnes)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nbLignes; i++) {
       // mettre le compteur de balles et de centres à 0
        for(int j = 0; j < nbColonnes;  j++){
            int choix = choix_case(nbColonnes);
            grille[i][j] = choix; // vide                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's totally clear what you want to achieve. This feels like an XY problem (at least a little), so it might help to say exactly what you want the code to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a Snake Vs block game, but for this part of the code, I only want to put values in my grid, from my 'count' variable. I do not want this variable to set to 0 every time I call it. So i need to find a way so that my counter does not reset everytime i call it. It works when i put my counter in my global variable ( int count = 0;) but I cannot do that for my assigment

Comment: Ok, so note that the returned count value is merely a count that will be one larger than whatever you get from `maximum(int)`. So it is unclear what the value of the calculated count gets you, since you can easily fetch this in the calling code using `maximum()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is really about debugging some code you've written, and not about a specific question about programming. You might need to back up and reassess. I'd recommend running this in an IDE and using simple debugging steps to work out where you are going wrong. See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The maximum  returns me the number of colums of the game ( variable nbColonnes) divided by 3. Because I cannot have more value than that for each ligns in my game.

Comment: Well, only thing I really want to know is, how can i put my count somewhere else, so that when i recall the function, it doesnt set itself to 0 everytime?

Comment: Yes, and then it loops until the count is > max. And since count is  incremented by one each iteration, this means count will be max + 1. The local random_value and count is never affects the rest of your code.

Comment: The local random_value returns random between 1 and 3, that part works when i debug it. The count also works, increment by 1, but only if I put it as a global variable. Thing is, i want my code to do the same thing, but without the count being a global variable

Comment: Yes, but all you do with the random value is use it to increment a count by the same amount, and you do this until it is maximum(int) + 1. The random values themselves are never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it *sounds* like you want the local `count` field to be saved on each call to `choix_case()`. i.e., it should be zero on first invocation and then each subsequent call should "remember" the previous count.

The easiest way to do this is have the calling code keep track of it, and pass it to `choix_case()`.

e.g.:

```
int cumlativeCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < nbLignes; i++) {
       // mettre le compteur de balles et de centres à 0
        for(int j = 0; j < nbColonnes;  j++){
            final int choix = choix_case(nbColonnes, cumlativeCount);
            grille[i][j] = choix; // vide  
            cumulativeCount = choix;              
        }
    }
```

This is assuming that `choix_case()` can be changed to accept another parameter.

But **please note** that this is actually not great code! The value you get back from `choix_case()` is a little pointless, since you *know* it is the value from `maximum(nbColonnes)` +1. It is unclear what `choix_case()` actually does, since none of its fields are ever used other than the count, and this count is easily figured out by the caller.

That is, `choix_case()` would behave exactly the same if it was:

```
do {
       if (random_value > 0) {
          count++;    
       }
    } while(count <= max);
return count;
```